# Highchart - Add dynamic data to the bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am using the bar chart. I want to add the new bar in the existing bar chart which is already drawn.

How to do that?
I have used the following

```
chartObject.series[i].addPoint(99, true);
```

But didn't get the result. It's automatically add the value with the default label name.

**I want to insert the E bar with the value under A**. How can I do that?

```
chartObject = Highcharts.chart('chartContainer', {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
            },

            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                },
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function () {
                                debugger


                                for (var i = 0; i < chartObject.series.length; i++) {
                                    chartObject.series[i].addPoint(99, true);

                                }

                                alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                showInLegend: false
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false

            },
            series: [{
                showInLegend: false,
                data: [
                    50,
                    35,
                    25,
                    80
                ]
            }]
        });
```

Comment: So, you want to achieve similar visual effect (one column under another) like here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-placement ?

Comment: Not like that.. Having same bar chart. Dynamically add new bar..

Comment: This is the code to add the value in the specific index. but the bar is not update. Bar has been drawn with the existing index. hippoChartIndicesChartObject.series[0].addPoint([4, 121] , false);

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/rhneon2q/

I think that one of the convenient ways to do this is to move categories definitions to *name* properties of points:

```
data: [
   {y: 50, name: 'A'},
   {y: 35, name: 'B'}
]
```

and change xAxis type to category:

```
type: 'category'
```

It's explained here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories

Then you can update chart with new point just like that:

**UPDATE:**

Code:

> ```
> chartObject.series[i].addPoint({y: this.y, name: 'E'}, true);
> ```

Adds new point with category on the end of a serie.

If you wan't new point with category to appear after the clicked one, you can use this code:

```
var data = chartObject.userOptions.series[i].data.slice(); // clone original userOptions
data.splice(this.index + 1, 0, {
  y: 10,
  name: "New cat. " + (chartObject.series[i].data.length - 2) // 2 - initial categories number
});
chartObject.series[i].update({
  data: data
});
```

**END OF UPDATE**

Unfortunately if you set categories like you did before:

```
categories: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

*name* property of added point won't be used as category.

Comment: You can see that 'E' is added below the 'A' and 'B'.. But I need like 'E' need to be created below the 'A'